# Error using iif in ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to fire this query in MS Access

```
SELECT file_number, 
    IIF(invoice_type='Spent on Coding',SUM(CINT(invoice_amount)), 0) as CodingExpense 
FROM invoice
GROUP BY file_number
```

I am getting this error

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.   Unable to
>   parse query text.

I tried replacing `IIF` with `SWITCH` to no avail.
What's wrong with my query and how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you need that round the other way:

```
Sum(IIF(invoice_type="Spent on Coding",CINT(invoice_amount), 0)) as CodingExpense
```

However, I would suggest:

```
Round(Sum(IIF(invoice_type="Spent on Coding",invoice_amount, 0)),0) as CodingExpense
```

Comment: this give me the same error in VS 2010 Server Explorer query pane. But it populates result when I press continue. interesting...

Comment: Get rid of CInt and see if you still have the problem, you can always round the result.